# Find $W(y_1 , y_2)$ where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are fundamental solutions of $x^2 y'' - 2 x^3 y' + \frac{1}{x^2} y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

> Find $W(y_1 , y_2)$ where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are fundamental solutions of $x^2 y'' - 2 x^3 y' + \frac{1}{x^2} y = 0$

I tried to find solutions on Wolfram yet haven't got any solutions but just stated "Sturm-Liouville". How do you find the Wronskian of the solutions of this D.E.?

Comment: Note that if $y_1,y_2$ is a fundamental basis, then so is $2y_1,y_2$ or $y_1,3y_2$ or $2y_1,2y_2$, each having a different Wronskian. You need at least to specify some initial point where the basis solutions have canonical values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2 y'' - 2 x^3 y' + \frac{1}{x^2} y = 0$$
$$y'' - 2 x y' + \frac{1}{x^4} y = 0$$
For the second order differential equation:
$$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$$
You can use [Abel's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity) 
$$W'=-p(x)W$$
$$\ln W=-\int p(x)dx$$